OpenSAML AuthnRequest signing doesn't work
I am working with openSAML in java, against Azure Entra SSO. My configuration works perfectly, however I now need to require the requests being signed.
I uploaded a certificate to Entra, as a .cer file with base64 content, without the --begin certificate-- and --end certificate-- binders, and this is my java code:
    private String encodeRequestMessage(RequestAbstractType requestMessage) {
        try {
            BasicX509Credential credential = new BasicX509Credential(loadCertificate(), loadPrivateKey());

            Signature signature = (Signature) XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getBuilderFactory().getBuilder(Signature.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME)
                    .buildObject(Signature.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);

            signature.setSigningCredential(credential);
            signature.setSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256);
            signature.setCanonicalizationAlgorithm(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);

            requestMessage.setSignature(signature);

            Marshaller marshaller = XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getMarshallerFactory().getMarshaller(requestMessage);
            Element authDOM = marshaller.marshall(requestMessage);

            Signer.signObject(signature);
            Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.DEFLATED, true);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            DeflaterOutputStream deflaterOutputStream =
                    new DeflaterOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream,
                            deflater);

            StringWriter rspWrt = new StringWriter();
            SerializeSupport.writeNode(authDOM, deflaterOutputStream);
            deflaterOutputStream.write(rspWrt.toString().getBytes());
            deflaterOutputStream.close();

            /* Encoding the compressed message */
            String encodedRequestMessage = Base64SamlEncoder.encodeBytes(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64SamlEncoder.DONT_BREAK_LINES);


            return URLEncoder.encode(encodedRequestMessage, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).trim();

        } catch (MarshallingException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

This is how I resolve the certificate and its matching private key:
    public static PrivateKey loadPrivateKey() throws Exception {
        try (PemReader reader = new PemReader(new StringReader(signingPrivateKey))) {
            byte[] keyBytes = reader.readPemObject().getContent();
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
        }
    }

    public static X509Certificate loadCertificate() throws Exception {
        try (InputStream fis = new StringBufferInputStream(signingCertificate)) {
            CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            return (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(fis);
        }
    }

however, I still get an error message from Azure saying my request is not signed. Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Check if this helps https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2012/11/verifying-signatures-with-opensaml.html
